# Linking to fullcalendar event

Tags: fullcalendar

i have a fullcalendar view, that shows the current month view as default. I fetch different events via json call, everything works fine.

My question is. How do i link to a specific event from another page, so that it opens in "day" view on the correct date.?

Comment: Your question is vague. Can you elaborate on "How do i link to a specific event from another page" ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/krJcL/

This leverages the `changeView` and `goToDate` FullCalendar methods to simulate what you need.

Might help you get started. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes kind of, the problem is though, that im linking from another page, i was looking for some kind of params i could set alongside the request... ?